# Recovering/Creating NewWorld Partition on Mac G4 (PPC) after botched Debian Install

Tags: linux, boot, debian, powerpc

I was trying to install Debian 5.04 on a Mac G4, and in typical geek tradition, I didn't  RTFM. During installation, I nuked all existing partitions, creating new to my liking.

But as I learned later during the installation process, yaboot needed a NewWorld partition, so I can't boot the installation. I don't have any OSX CDs with me (this is a used G4 I purchased of craigslist) with which to create a HFS partition. I've re-run the Debian installer, which lets me create a partition that is supposed to be of type 'NewWorld', but the installer does not seem to like it or recognizes it.

Any ideas how to proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably get a better response on superuser.com where this question really belongs.

Comment: Thanks for moving it to superuser. I thought about it, but didn't know for certain which site was more appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The problem was that during partitioning, a 32kb "Apple" partition would remain at the start of the cylinders, even if I choose to partition the entire disk. That would cause my selection of partitions to fail (thus failing to create the NewWorld partition.)

The solution was to leave the 32kb partition alone, partitioning the rest in any way I wanted (including the addition of the NewWorld partition.) Once that was done, the install ran perfectly; yaboot was installed on NewWorld; and the box came up to life. Yay!